How to get corfu-popupinfo working with ESS[R]?
company-quickhelp provides short documentation for arguments in ESS. I read that corfu-popupinfo should be equivalent, but it doesn't seem to be working out of box. When I type in aov(for and press C-M-i I get completion candidates for the names of arguments. However, I cannot seem to use corfu-popupinfo-toggle (M-t) to get documentation on what these arguments do. Is anyone using ESS with corfu?

I am using, https://github.com/lf-araujo/MxNotebook, but I cannot make corfu-popup work with ESS no matter what I try.
